# How to access keyof dynamic key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a `Basket` interface, tracking how many products a person has in their basket, where product names are unknown beforehand.

```
interface Basket {
  [productName: string]: number;
}
```

Let's say the person can select one product from their basket as their `favouriteProduct`. Like so:

```
interface User {
  basket: Basket;
  favoriteProduct: string;
}
```

But I want to ensure `favoriteProduct` is a key in `Basket`. For example:

```
// I want this to compile
const user1: User = {
  basket: {
    milk: 1,
    bread: 2,
  },
  favoriteProduct: "milk",
}


// I want this to throw an error
const user2: User = {
  basket: {
    milk: 1,
    bread: 2,
  },
  favoriteProduct: "potato",
}
```

Is this possible in TypeScript? I tried this, but it does not seem to work, probably because I have dynamic keys in `Basket`.

```
interface User {
  basket: Basket;
  favoriteProduct: keyof Basket;
}
```

Comment: `{ [productName: string]: number; }` is an index signature, so this is declaring that there is `number` value for **any** string key.  You cannot find the the specific keys of a type with an index signature because by definition, the key type is `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but not without making `User` generic in order to have the actual keys that are present in `Basket`. I am assuming here we are talking about keys that can differ, but that are known at compile time (keys known only at runtime can't be validated by typescript)

```
interface User<T extends Basket> {
  basket: T;
  favoriteProduct: keyof T;
}


// I want this to compile
const user1: User<{ milk: number, bread: number }> = {
  basket: {
    milk: 1,
    bread: 2,
  },
  favoriteProduct: "milk",
}


// I want this to throw an error
const user2: User<{ milk: number, bread: number }> = {
  basket: {
    milk: 1,
    bread: 2,
  },
  favoriteProduct: "potato",
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4GsJmQbwChlkBtABygHsATAVwTADk4BbCALmQzClAHMAulxB1WAI2gBuQgF9CC0JFiIUAVQzQAPABVkEAB6QQNDGkw4wAPgLFk4i7i46ZJeADcqfSAAVq9Ri4cAE8qGGQXOQVCAHoY5ABJZAB3OHBkMAALYDMwKmQEKlZyYAAbCEJCkB5kOk0oAEYuDW18ZFYyrBExSSgAGnsoCDgaboloZFkbAF5bEgdsJzmSds6uBr67eaGRrgAmTZJZQ+QPL2BffwYwLgAiDtKsW835BTjElLS8LJyM-KzqMlkGl9FBqFBKlRqng6tA9s16lo2g8ushRON+oNhqM0T0JlNkLMiPNHDdliQUesTttsfsTsc7GdvBA-LRrndyFQwHA8s85EA)

You could also use a function to infer `T` for `User` so you don't have to type it explicitly:

```
function createUser<T extends Basket>(u:User<T>) {
    return u
}

// I want this to compile
const user1 = createUser({
  basket: {
    milk: 1,
    bread: 2,
  },
  favoriteProduct: "milk",
})


// I want this to throw an error
const user2 = createUser({
  basket: {
    milk: 1,
    bread: 2,
  },
  favoriteProduct: "potato",
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4GsJmQbwChlkBtABygHsATAVwTADk4BbCALmQzClAHMAulxB1WAI2gBuQgF9CC0JFiIUAVQzQAPABVkEAB6QQNDGkw4wAPgLFk4i7i46ZJeADcqfSAAVq9Ri4cAE8qGGQXOUIYOhBGYCoQZAQoCDhIDW09Q2NTc2xcKwAKOg5MqF0rAEpbEhJUsDooJLoowgB6duQASWQAdzhwZDAAC2AzMCpkqlZyYAAbCEIERJ5kOk0oAEZkAF5k1PSIcqKiEgcCsC4zutYFrC4tgBo7c8OaLgAmF5JZH+QPF5gL5-AwrsgAER3eZYCEvWRVBQdLq9AZDUbjYZTUbUPrIQb6KDUKDLVZ4DbQT57A5pDKbU52C6Wa6vZDQh7IZ6s8TvL7-P52QHeCB+WhgrgQ8hUMDpKhwuRVKRAA)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the quick response.